# Converting numbers into time in R

Tags: regex, r

My data looks like this:

```
 > str(m)
     int [1:8407] 930 1050 1225 1415 1620 1840 820 1020 1215 1410 ...
```

This is the time in hours and minutes. I'm trying to turn it into something (9:30, 12:10, 16:40, 8:25...).

```
> m1 <- strptime(m, "%H%M")
> head(m1)
[1] NA                         "2015-10-14 10:50:00 VLAT"
[3] "2015-10-14 12:25:00 VLAT" "2015-10-14 14:15:00 VLAT"
[5] "2015-10-14 16:20:00 VLAT" "2015-10-14 18:40:00 VLAT"
> str(m1)
 POSIXlt[1:8407], format: NA "2015-10-14 10:50:00" "2015-10-14 12:25:00" ...
```

How to convert a set of digits in time?

Comment: Try  `sub('(.{2})(.{2})', '\\1:\\2',sprintf('%04d', v1))`

Comment: Do you just want the look to change or does your task require one of the date classes?

Comment: I didn't understand how the `1050` got converted to `12:10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We format the numbers with `sprintf` to  pad leading 0 for 3 digit numbers, use `strptime` and then use `format` to get the hour and min.

```
format(strptime(sprintf('%04d', v1), format='%H%M'), '%H:%M')
#[1] "09:30" "10:50" "12:25"
```

Or another option is

```
sub('(\\d{2})$', ':\\1', v1)
#[1] "9:30"  "10:50" "12:25"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c(930, 1050,1225)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex:

```
sub("(\\d{2})$", ":\\1", x)
 #[1] "9:30"  "10:50" "12:25" "14:15" "16:20" "18:40" "8:20" 
 #[8] "10:20" "12:15" "14:10"
```

A match is made on the last two digits and adds a colon before it.

**Data**

```
x <- c(930, 1050, 1225, 1415, 1620, 1840, 820, 1020, 1215, 1410)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is,

```
x <- c(645, 1234,2130)
substr(as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04.0f", x), format='%H%M'), 12, 16)

#[1] "06:45" "12:34" "21:30"
```